# How to check if a table has columnstore index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, columnstore

I need to make some mechanism that checks if a table X is columnstored or not and if it is not to convert it. 
I am aware that to convert a table X for example to clustered columnstore index we can use the following code:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX MyColumnStoreIndex
ON Table_X
```

I would like to make a query that checks if a table contains columnstore index.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation about indexes indicates quite clearly how to find this information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query sys.indexes and check the type and type_desc columns. [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) values 5 and 6 hold information whether an index is clustered or nonclustered columnstore:

```
select *
from sys.indexes 
where type in (5, 6)
```

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

you can query the sys.indexes as mentioned in Rigerta's answer.
To also get the tablename that belongs to found indexes you can do following query

```
select i.name as indexname, 
       t.name as tablename
from   sys.indexes i
  join sys.tables t on i.object_id = t.object_id
where  i.type in (5, 6)
```